# How many perfect squares are there between $n$ and $2n$

Tags: number-theory

Let's define the $S_n$ set as $x\in S_n | n <= x^2 <= 2n $ (and everything is a positive integer). What do we know about $|Sn|$ (number of elements of $S_n$)? In [Proving that there is a perfect square between $n$ and $2n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190737/proving-that-there-is-a-perfect-square-between-n-and-2n) we have seen it is at least 1. What else do we know about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of squares at most equal to $a$ is $\lfloor \sqrt a \rfloor$.

So, the number of squares between $n$ and $2n$, inclusive, is
$$
\lfloor \sqrt {2n} \rfloor - \lfloor \sqrt{n-1} \rfloor
$$

Ignoring the floors in the expression, we get
$$
S_n \approx \sqrt {2n} - \sqrt{n-1} \sim (\sqrt 2-1) \sqrt n \quad \text{as } n \to \infty.
$$
This approximations seems to be quite good even for small $n$ such as $100$.

Comment: Yes, I suspected the answer to be some $C \times \sqrt n$ as $n \to \infty$. Is this proof that $C = \sqrt 2 - 1$ or just a good approximation?

Comment: @chx, $\sqrt {2n} - \sqrt{n-1} \sim (\sqrt 2-1) \sqrt n$ means $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt {2n} - \sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt n} =  \sqrt 2-1$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize $\sim$ is not $\approx$. Thanks!